# How to open a socket from an android phone without getting a SocketException run time error?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to write an app on android where, there is a  multithreaded server running on a computer and in the app on the phone there is a button, once the user clicks that button a socket is opened between the server and the client. My problem is that once the user clicks that button I get a lot of runtime errors on my log cat. One of them is SocketException socket failed (Permission denied)

Here is the code for the activity that has the button that opens the socket with the server

```
package guc.edu.eg;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Activity1 extends Activity {
    Button start;
    Button help;
    Button credentials;
    Socket socket;
     //public DataInputStream in=null;
     public PrintStream out=null;
     InetAddress IP;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);
        //try {
            //IP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        //} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // //TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
        //}
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    socket= new Socket("127.0.0.1",4444);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //try {
                    //out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    //out.println ("The socket is open at the phone!!");
                //} catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                //}
                //try {
                    // in = new 
                      //DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            //  } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //  e.printStackTrace();
                //}
                Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        help = (Button) findViewById(R.id.help);
        help.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity3.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        });
        credentials = (Button) findViewById(R.id.credentials);
        credentials.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity4.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the Server class, that is actually placed in a different project other than the one that has the app code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;


// Java extension packages


public class Server implements Runnable {


    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket clientSocket;
    int portNo;

    LinkedList<ServerThread> allClients = new LinkedList<ServerThread>();

    public Server(int port) {
        portNo = port;


    }

    public void run() {

        try {

            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNo);

            while (true) {


                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();


                ServerThread x = new ServerThread(clientSocket, this);
                allClients.add(x);

                x.start();


            }
        } catch (EOFException eofException) {
            System.out.println("Client terminated connection");
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendMessageToClient(String message) {
        String[] x = message.split(",");
        //for (int i = 0; i < allClients.size(); i++) {
            //if (allClients.get(i).clientName.equals(x[2])) {
                //allClients.get(i).sendMessage(x[1] + ": " + x[0]);
                //return;
            //}
        //}     
        // if you didn't return then you couldn't reach your destination in your local server
        // send the message to the network server to search for it
    }

    public String getLocalClientsNames() {
        String names = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < allClients.size(); i++) {
            names += allClients.get(i).clientName + ",";
        }
        return names;
    }

    public void sendClientNamesToAll() {
        //net.sendAllClientNames();
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Server server = new Server(4444);
        new Thread(server).start();
    }

}
```

Here is the ServerThread class placed at the same package with the Server class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;


public class ServerThread extends Thread {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private Server server;


    String clientName;

    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;

    public ServerThread(Socket client, Server s) {
        this.clientSocket = client;
        this.server = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            output.flush();
            input = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

            processConnection();
            closeConnection();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("in or out failed");
        }
    }

    private void processConnection() throws IOException {

        String message = "!!";

        System.out.println("mada5alsh el while");

        while (!message.equalsIgnoreCase("Client>> end")) {

            try {
                System.out.println("da5al el while");
                message = (String) input.readObject();
                System.out.print(message);
                if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("Name")) {
                    clientName = (String) input.readObject();
                    server.sendClientNamesToAll();
                } else {



                    server.sendMessageToClient(message);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void closeConnection() throws IOException {

        output.close();
        input.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        try {
            output.writeObject(message);
            output.flush();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            //do
        }
    }

}
```

1. I think it might be something that has to do with the manifest file so I added this line of code to it

   ```
        `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You create your client socket in the main thread which is not permitted.

Use a separate thread or use AsyncTask.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion, but how exactly do I do that!?

Comment: In the right margin of this html page you see many -blue- Related topics. Read them all. One of them which shows how to create a thread for a client is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323100/exception-in-connecting-android-tcp-client-to-java-tcp-server

Answer (score 0):

Adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>` to you AndroidManifest.xml should do the trick.